# Spring Web Service with Header and Body In Envelope

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

We are creating a webservice that came from a WSDL which the soap messagehas both a header and body in the request and response.  How can you set this up to work with a Spring WS?  I can not find any examples????

**In WSDL**

```
<wsdl11:message name="createCourseSectionRequest">
<wsdl11:part name="Parameters" element="tns:createCourseSectionRequest"/>
<wsdl11:part name="HeaderInfoParameters" element="tns:imsx_syncRequestHeaderInfo"/>
</wsdl11:message>
<wsdl11:message name="createCourseSectionResponse">
<wsdl11:part name="Response" element="tns:createCourseSectionResponse"/>
<wsdl11:part name="HeaderInfoResponse" element="tns:imsx_syncResponseHeaderInfo"/>
</wsdl11:message>
```

**Endpoint**

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart="CreateCourseSectionRequest", namespace="")
    @ResponsePayload
    public CreateCourseSectionResponse createCourseSection(CreateCourseSectionRequest req) {

        //TODO 
        return null;
    }
```

**Example**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ims="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/cmsv1p0/wsdl11/sync/imscms_v1p0">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ims:imsx_syncRequestHeaderInfo>
         <ims:imsx_version>?</ims:imsx_version>
         <ims:imsx_messageIdentifier>?</ims:imsx_messageIdentifier>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ims:imsx_sendingAgentIdentifier>?</ims:imsx_sendingAgentIdentifier>
      </ims:imsx_syncRequestHeaderInfo>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      .....
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Did you make any progress on this or do you need help?

Comment: Still need help, looks like an option is to use an interceptor and send the header info in the endpoint method, not sure.

Comment: Yeah - that is an approach. You could create a class that extends EndpointInterceptor and you can override the handleRequest and handleResponse methods to add your custom logic that deals with the header information. (Sorry if the answer is too abstract.(on a commute). I can add more information if you are not able to proceed)

Comment: If you had a full blown example then yes, if not dont worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with.  It works, but I wish the header part of the Soap message was strongly typed.  .NET takes care of this for you while in Java it looks like you have to do more work to replicate a strongly typed object for the header.  At least I can access the request/response header of the envelope with MessageContext.

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart="readCourseSectionRequest", namespace="http://www.imsglobal.org/services/lis/cmsv1p0/wsdl11/sync/imscms_v1p0")
    @ResponsePayload
    public ReadCourseSectionResponse readCourseSection(@RequestPayload ReadCourseSectionRequest parameters, MessageContext messageContext) {

        //SaajSoapMessage response = (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();
        //SoapHeader header = response.getSoapHeader();
        //header.addHeaderElement(new QName("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "MessageID", parameters.getSourcedId()));

        return new ReadCourseSectionResponse();
    }
```